# What does "綺麗" mean in this sentence?

Tags: translation

Been reading a manga where a tsundere character says this line:

> 何ですか？事あるごとに私のことを『可愛い』だとか！
>       『お姉さんになって』『綺麗だ』『甘えたい』とか！
>       『特攻がわかりにくい』とか！

The 2nd line here is a problem for me. Am I right to say the 綺麗 here doesn't act as the adjective to 姉さん? Does it mean "completely, entirely" in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd read it as...

> 何ですか？事あるごとに私のことを『可愛い』だとか！
>   『お姉さんになって』『綺麗だ』『甘えたい』とか！
>   『特攻がわかりにくい』とか！

I think the character is saying "What do you mean by telling [these phrases in brackets: 'Please be my big sister' 'You're gorgeous' etc.] to me at every opportunity / on every occasion?"